# Web server is now only accessible in localhost

Tags: apache-http-server

My web server (Apache 2.4 (from ms4w package) on Windows Server 2012) is now only accessible in localhost and I don't know why. It worked fine and then the router and the switch has been replaced. The IT transfered the VPN server from Windows Server 2012 to the router (Ubiquiti network gear) too.

Now Apache, running on port 8079, isn't accessible by the others in the network, only in localhost. But from the machine running the unreachable  web server, I can access the same installation package (ms4w+apache) just fine on another computer in the network.

By the way, PostgreSQL is still working fine.

I also disabled the firewall and the antivirus without success.

Have any idea?

EDIT:

netstat -ano | find ":8079"

[image]

Comment: what does `netstat -ano | find ":8079"` return?

Comment: I edited my question with the result

Comment: What do you mean when you say "only accessible [from] localhost"? What exactly happens when you try from some other host?

Comment: Other computers in the LAN used have access to the web server. Now they can't reach it. The only way to reach the web server is from the server machine itself (127.0.0.1:8079).